# Access 2007 need to Force a query update based on a field change in a form?

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have an access database with several calculated fields in text boxes on a form.  Most of those update immediately after the data included in the calculation is updated.   However I have a couple of those calculated field text boxes that include a data point from a Query, when I update a filed that would impact the query results, those calculated fields do not update correctly until I click through a few records or close and open the form.

How can I force that specific query to update after updating a specific filed on the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try refreshing the form.

```
Me.Refresh
```

As an aside, you really should get out of the habit of using bound forms, because you have to end up kludging a bunch of stuff (like this) to get it to work properly, and the Undo functionality (cancelling the entry of a new record) is unstable at best.  By unbinding a form, you can have more control over how it reacts to calculated fields and dumping a new data entry is a snap.

Comment: Bound forms are extremely useful. How is calling your manually coded data-load function less kludgy than calling `Form.Refresh`? Not planning to get into a discussion here, but I can't let this stand as an absolute truth.